# Correlation coefficient formula

Tags: statistics

I have an issue with understanding the formula in the reference.

**For the left-hand side of the equation:**

I assume that 'n' comes from the denominator, where they omitted
1/n twice in the calculations of the standard deviation.

This would lead to the denominator having one of the factors:

sqrt(1/n^2) = 1/n. Because 1/n is in the denominator, it could be pushed to the numerator as n.

So the LHS makes sense.

**RHS:**

As the calculation of st.dev is already performed, both 1/n factors are included in that calculation, so there is no reason for the whole term to be multiplied by 'n'.

**Question 1:** Do you guys think this is a typo? Or am I missing something?

**Question 2:** When looking at the Wikipedia: they seem to be using 1/(n-1) rather than n. I am wondering where does this term come from? Again, isn't 1/N-1 ( for sample) included in the calculation of st.dev?

Reference:
[Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04rfekUsVrI&feature=youtu.be&list=PLBv09BD7ez_50pj5kcKFYee7QPcg3ImCV/)

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#For_a_population)

Comment: This is not the correlaition coefficient in the video, it is n times the correlation coefficient.

Comment: @callculus yeah, but why would they do that? It is describing the correlation coefficient

Comment: I don´t know. I
 would recommend to leave a comment below the video.